# Delete from Firebase in an Adapter class

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, removechild

Hi so I am trying to delete an item from Firebase Realtime database. I can get it to delete from the Recycler View however it doesn't delete from Firebase.

Currently, I am trying to delete the item through clicking on a delete button in a recyclerview item and I am putting the code for this in the adapter java class.

Is there anything I am missing in order to get it to delete from firebase?

My code for the Adapter:

```
public class DailyMealAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DailyMealAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<SelectedMeal> selectedMealList;

    private DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Meals");

    public DailyMealAdapter(Context c, List<SelectedMeal> sm) {
        context = c;
        selectedMealList = sm;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dailymeal_item, parent, false);

        DailyMealAdapter.MyViewHolder viewHolder = new DailyMealAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final int itemPos = position;
        final SelectedMeal selectedMeal = selectedMealList.get(position);
        holder.mealTitle.setText(selectedMeal.getMealName());
        holder.mealCalories.setText(selectedMeal.getCalorieAmount());

        holder.mealDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
          selectedMealList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemChanged(position, selectedMealList.size());
            final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Meals");
            final ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    dataSnapshot.getValue(SelectedMeal.class);
                    ref.child(selectedMealList.get(position).getMealId()).removeValue();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            };
            //ref.child(String.valueOf(selectedMealList.get(Integer.parseInt(selectedMeal.getMealId())))).removeValue();
            //deleteMeal(selectedMeal.getMealId(), itemPos);
        }
    });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return selectedMealList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mealTitle, mealCalories;
        public Button mealDelete;
        public CardView cardView;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mealTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dailyMealTitle);
            mealCalories = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dailyMealCalories);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dailyCardView);
            mealDelete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you share stack trace. What is the problem.

Comment: The error is :  java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:96)
        at com.example.calorie2food.Adapters.DailyMealAdapter$1.onClick(DailyMealAdapter.j

Comment: that means selectedMeal.getMealId()  is null.

Comment: What reasons would make that null? I have tried various different ways to do this and that is the same error I get everytime

Comment: Did you check the selectedMealList. Is the mealId null??

Comment: I have actually changed my code abit and it deletes from the recycler view but does not delete from Firebase

Comment: I just ask you check the selectedMealList

Comment: It comes up invalid to type SelectedMealList.getMealId()

Comment: No, like this = selectedMealList.get(position).getMealId()

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't come back null however it now deletes from the Recycler View but does not delete from Firebase

Comment: Can you update the question

Comment: Question has now been updated

Comment: your code is a bit confused

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView mealTitle, mealCalories;
        public Button mealDelete;
        public CardView cardView;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mealTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dailyMealTitle);
            mealCalories = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dailyMealCalories);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dailyCardView);
            mealDelete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
            mealDelete.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ref.child(selectedMealList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getMealId()).removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        selectedMealList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                        notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

onBindViewHolder clean as like

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final int itemPos = position;
    final SelectedMeal selectedMeal = selectedMealList.get(position);
    holder.mealTitle.setText(selectedMeal.getMealName());
    holder.mealCalories.setText(selectedMeal.getCalorieAmount());
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried that however, the same error still came about about the nullpointer

Comment: So selectedMealList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getMealId()) is null. You said not null

Comment: I changed the code though and selectedMealList.get(position).getMealId() worked. I added the new code into the question when I updated it

Comment: You don't need eventListener.

Comment: Can you share your firebase db. and how do you get meals list.

Comment: Do you know any other way around ensuring the value does no become null?

Comment: How can it be null? You said that is not null

Comment: but If you are saying to not do it with an eventListener, It comes back null

Comment: Also  you do not use the event listener. You just created it. Share db and how do you get list

Comment: selectedMealList.remove(position); if you call this method first. Then selectedMealList.get(position).getMealId() would be null. You should use as my answer

Comment: Hi, I ask you share your database